# How to fit log returns to an AR() model in R?

Tags: regression

I have a series of daily log returns and I am looking to fit them to an AR() process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question will likely be perceived as too broad to be suitable for this site, because it appears you are asking for a tutorial on time series analysis.  Please narrow its scope (or find a tutorial and return with any specific questions that occur).

Comment: The literal answer to your question is to use the `arima()` function but I suspect you're asking something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is to look at the sample autocorrelation function (ACF).  If it is a stationary AR(p) process it the ACF will decline toward 0 exponentially.  If it is positive and slowly declining it is probably non stationary and trend removal will be needed prior to fitting a staionary time series model.  If the ACF has the characteristics of an AR(p) process the ACF and the partial autocorrelation function can be used to help you find the order of the model.  See the book by Box, Jenkins and Reinsel for all the details about this.  There are many software packages that you can use to fit the model.  SAS/ETS is one.  SPSS, Minitab and other large packages also have this capability.  IrishStat (Dave Reilly) who participates on this website has autobox a software package that will do the whole three stages of modeling (indentification, fitting and diagnostic checking) automatically for you. In R the arima function that Macro referred to can be used.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Do you by any chance happen to know how to interpret the output of the acf2A() function, which returns a matrix?

Comment: I am not familiar with R functions.  The ACF for a single time series is 1-dimensional.  Are you fitting a single series or a vector of time series?

Comment: Thats what I expected the output to be. Its the acf for a multifractal random walk model, called acf.mrw. If I plot the acf it is decaying exponentially toward 0. The acf output is then exactly fitted to an AR() process by the function acf2ar(). The output is a matrix which I then dont understand how to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

As for AR model, you may refer to [this](http://www.statoek.wiso.uni-goettingen.de/veranstaltungen/zeitreihen/sommer03/ts_r_intro.pdf). For R, the [TSA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSA/index.html) package is a good one to use. The writer of the package has easily understandable [class notes](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~kchan/TSA.htm).

*If you have a specific example, I can provide you further help.*

Answer (score 1):

In R, if `x` is your vector of log returns, just use

```
fit <- ar(x)
```

That will fit the best AR model using the AIC. Much easier than looking at ACF/PACF plots.

Comment: Thanks, I get the same results as before but this way is obviously way easier. Is there an equivalently easy way to fit an AR() process to a matrix?

Comment: The help files are helpful. Please read them. In this case, it says that x may be a univariate or multivariate time series.